# initialization by lambda expression in c++

Tags: c++, lambda

i write follow code：

```
static int count = []()->int
                   {
                       int count = 0;

                       for(int i = 0; i < categories.size(); ++i)
                       {
                           if(!categories[i].isCategory())
                           {
                               count++;
                           }
                       }

                       return count;
                   };
```

and got error:`error: cannot convert '__lambda0' to 'int' in initialization`.

does the meaning of my code fragment is assign the `__lambda0` to `static int count` instead of return the inner count?

Comment: Yes, you're assigning the lambda (function), not its evaluation. You need to actually invoke the lambda.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You aren't calling it! Make sure you do so:

```
static int count = []()->int
                   {
                       int count = 0;

                       for(int i = 0; i < categories.size(); ++i)
                       {
                           if(!categories[i].isCategory())
                           {
                               count++;
                           }
                       }

                       return count;
                   }();
                 // ^^ THIS THIS THIS THIS
```

BUT, IMHO, you're better off in this without using a lambda. And in the case where you'd use it in other parts of your code, then have it in a stand-alone (not lambda) function.

Comment: I think this is a valid use-case. It might be a static local, and the lambda could depend on other locals. (But this example doesn't show anything get captured.)

Answer (score 2):

> does the meaning of my code fragment is assign the `__lambda0` to `static int count` instead of return the inner count?

Exactly. To call the lambda, just add `()` at the end.

```
                   …
               } ();
```